# C++ constructor calling order

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor

When I initialize an object of my class, both the default and copy constructor are called.

```
class A
{
public:
   A (string s) { str = string (s); cout << "default" << endl; }
   A (int n) { cout << "A (int n)" << endl; }
   A (string s, int n) { cout << "A (string s, int n)" << endl; }
   A (int n2, string s2) { cout << "A (int n2, string s2)" << endl; }
   A (const A& a) { str = a.str; cout << "copy" << endl; }

   inline void printA () { cout << str << endl; }

   string str;
};


int main (void)
{
   A a_1 = A ("con 1");
   cout << endl;

   A a_2 = "con 2";
   cout << endl;

   A a_3 = A (4);

   A a_4 = A ("a_4", 10);
   cout << endl;

   A a_5 = A (11, "a_5");
   cout << endl;

   cin.get();
   return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
default
copy

default

A (int n)

A (string s, int n)
copy

A (int n2, string s2)
copy
```

Why do `a_1`, `a_3`, and `a_4` call both the default and the copy constructors?
A_3 also has a single argument, but it doesn't need copy constructor.

Comment: Why would you add a default constructor?

Comment: @curiousguy: i guess to more clearly describe the problem here. I could have made this:    `A () { cout << "default" << endl; }` and change current default constructor to: `A (string s) { str = string (s); cout << "A (string s)" << endl; }` to be get better debug info. Also if you make `Foo()` private, this constructor becomes unavailable outside of class. And then, there is `explicit` keyword which does what i cant remember :) AFAIK that's it.

Comment: @MartinBerger Please edit "_Why is A_1 calling default_" out of your question.

Comment: @Martin: You don't need the default constructor, I was just saying that the constructor that outputs "default" is not a default constructor, and so is the claim that the default constructor is called is just wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> A a_1 = A ("con 1");

Constructs a temporary object by calling the constructor which takes a string as an argument,since the passed type is `const char *` the compiler has to perform an implicit conversion first to `string`() and then uses this temporary object to copy construct a new `a_1` object.
*Since there is an additional implicit conversion the compiler cannot optimize this and needs to make the call to the copy constructor.*
Based on the comments and further research I am doubtful if the(above *italicized*)reasoning is correct.

@David suggests in his comments:
*the copy can not be elided not because of implicit conversion, but rather because the conversion is explicit. That is, the compiler cannot optimize it because the code explicitly request the creation of the temporary and the copy construction.*

However, neither @David nor Me are able to substantiate it through a Standard Citation.

> A a_2 = "con 2";

constructs object `a_2` by calling the appropriate constructor which takes string as an argument.

> A a_3 = A (4);

*The note in Case 1 also applies here:*
Should Ideally Construct a temporary object by calling the constructor which takes integer as an argument and then use this temporary object to copy construct a new `a_3` object as in case 1, but the compiler can optimize and directly construct the object by calling constructor which takes integer as one is available.

> A a_4 = A ("a_4", 10);

Constructs a temporary object by calling the constructor which takes string and integer as an argument and then uses this temporary object to copy construct a new `a_4` object.

> A a_5 = A (11, "a_5");

Constructs a temporary object by calling the constructor which takes integer and string as an argument and then uses this temporary object to copy construct a new `a_5` object.

Note that you do not have an Default constructor defined for your class.

You can achieve the same in a more efficient manner by avoiding the creation of the temporary and then copy constructing an object in above cases by not using the assignment(`=`).

```
A a_1("con 1");
A a_2("con 2");
A a_3(4);
A a_4("a_4", 10);
A a_5(11, "a_5");
```

---

My Initial answer was on attempt to explain the behavior but as I compile this on gcc-4.3.4 on **[Ideone](http://www.ideone.com/MssZD)**, I find that gcc is intelligent enough to optimize the copy constructor call.None of the cases invoke the copy constructor.

The conclusion I come to is, Each compiler depending on its intelligence can or cannot optimize copy constructor calls in such as case, While the Standard does not require the compiler to perform such optimization each compiler evaluates such expressions depending on their capabilities.

If I am wrong on this  please free to add me an comment with reasoning.

Comment: This is wrong. There is no copy construction in `a_3`; OP is asking why this is the case, given that the copy construction happens in all other cases.

Comment: @Gorpik: Thanks corrected.Got a little carried away with cntrl+c cntrl+v :)

Comment: @Als: Case a_1: but even if i have constructor like this: `A (string s) { str = string (s); cout << "A (string s)" << endl; }` and use this line: `A a_7 = A (string("a_7"));` the copy constructor gets called. And there is no implicit type conversion. Why is this? Compiler has adequate constructor to optimize.

Comment: @MartinBerger: What compiler are you using?

Comment: @MartinBerger The compiler also has no requirement whatsoever to optimize that.

Comment: @MarkB: Yes,but gcc performs exceedingly well in this case and performs the necessary optimization's, check the Ideone link in my updated answer.

Comment: @Als: i saw it. Nice. So it is up to compiler to choose. Other cases (a_*) i understand. Any time i use `Foo f_1 = Foo (?)` compiler creates temporary object and uses copy constructor and it just may, depending on its intelligence, optimize. So i should use `Foo f_1 (?)`. Thank you all for putting effort to this question and especially to Als!

Comment: @MartinBerger: Indeed you should get rid of the `=` and then you don't have to deal with the additionally generated temporaries,Just out of curiosity,what compiler are you using?

Comment: As for compiler, as i am using VS2010 IDE, i think that compiler is called VS2010.

Comment: This is all wrong: `=` is not assignment, "_Since there is an additional implicit conversion the compiler cannot optimize_" has no justification, `A a_2 = "con 2";` means construct a temp `A("con 2")` then initialise `a_2`, the temporary is fused into `a_2`. I can't believe this got 6 upvotes!

Comment: @MartinBerger "_The compiler also has no requirement whatsoever to optimize that_" There is no requirement whatsoever to use such a bad compiler.

Comment: @curiousguy: Elaborate on What is wrong? I can't believe you cannot read it! A compiler shows this behavior and the answer tries to explain the behavior of *that* compiler,the answer also states the behavior for gcc and concludes on a note.

Comment: @Als "_I can't believe you cannot read it!_" I cannot read what?

Comment: @curiousguy: i got myself night build of CodeBlocks yesterday with MinGW compiler :)

Comment: @curiousguy: i agree with Als for that one. Also there is no assignment anywhere in my code. Assignment only happens if object (A_*) was already created.

Comment: The first case is worst, the copy can not be elided not because of *implicit* conversion, but rather because the conversion is *explicit*. That is, the compiler cannot optimize it because the code *explicitly* request the creation of the temporary and the copy construction. Compare it with the second case where the conversion is actually *implicit* and the compiler optimises it away. The actual sequence in 1 is: conversion from literal to string, construction of temporary from string and finally the copy construction. Your description is missing the intermediate step

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Thanks for that elaboration ,Are there any rules laid out by the standard regarding this? I believe the compilers can just do the optimization depending on their abilities because gcc(Ideone link in answer) just optimizes all the copy constructor calls off while msvc2010 as OP claims gives above output.

Comment: I believe that the the standard makes return value optimization (RVO) optional in all cases.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas "_That is, the compiler cannot optimize it because the code explicitly request the creation of the temporary and the copy construction._" Citation?

Comment: @Als "_Also there is no assignment anywhere in my code._" I agree. That's what I am saying.

Comment: @Als: I have briefly browsed the relevant parts of the standard, and I see no reason that would block that optimization from being performed, but I remember reading a few years ago an article stating that if the call to the constructor was *explicit* in the code, then the compiler *wouldn't* perform that optimization, where I don't recall whether *wouldn't* there meant *is not allowed to* or *would commonly not*. At any rate, the explanation provided for that first case is still wrong.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: How is the first case(`a_1`) different from the third(`a_3`) case then, in which the very same compiler could actually elide the copy?

Comment: Beats me. As I said, I remember reading that some time ago, but that was when I was younger and believed what I read without verifying against the standard. After just looking at the standard, I cannot positively stand by my previous claim, I have found no reason why the standard would inhibit the optimization in the first case, which does not mean that the compiler is obliged to perform that optimization either. What I can positively say is that *implicit conversions* have nothing to do with it, as the only implicit conversion is from `const char*` to `std::string` which is also present in 2.

Comment: @MichaelPrice "_I believe that the the standard makes return value optimization (RVO) optional in all cases._" Indeed.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas "_if the call to the constructor was explicit in the code_" There is no such thing as an "explicit" constructor call. The closest thing is placement new, which cannot be optimised away.

Comment: BTW, I was there when the rules for object confusion were defined. So I know the intent well.

Answer (score 6):

To avoid the superfluous copy constructor calls, eliminate the `=` and use this syntax to call the desired constructor directly:

```
A a_1("con 1");
A a_2("con 2");
A a_3(4);
A a_4("a_4", 10);
A a_5(11, "a_5");
```

Comment: There are no default constructor calls here.

Comment: BTW, "_this syntax to call the desired constructor directly_" is called **direct**-initialisation.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you are doing an implicit conversions. When you construct `a_1`, you are using a `const char*`, which gets implicitly converted into a `std::string`, which is fed into the `A` constructor and then copy constructed. When you construct `a_3`, there is no implicit conversion involved, so the compiler is allowed to skip the copy constructor and construct `a_3` directly with the `int`.

Comment: Allright. Thank you for contributing up there in Als post. +1

Comment: Can you please back up this answer?

Comment: @curiousguy: I think the standard does not explicitly prohibit skipping the copy constructor in case 3; but it prohibits chaining two implicit conversions. This prohibition allow some proxy classes to work correctly. The compiler may have a hard time knowing whether skipping the copy constructor would lead to a violation of that prohibition, so it just does not do it.

Comment: "_but it prohibits chaining two implicit conversions_" It does not.

Comment: @curiousguy: Not exactly two implicit conversions, true, but it prohibits two user-defined implicit conversions. See 13.3.3.1 in C++11.

Comment: @Gorpik No, it does no such thing. You are making this up.

Answer (score -6):

## Short answer

Nobody here knows. **You should ask the compiler writer.**

Or get another compiler.

There is no fundamental reason for this inconsistent behaviour.

## Detailed answer

1) compiler behaviour shown is inconsistent

2) only the compiler author could answer this question why compiler behaviour is inconsistent - and maybe not even him, you would need to browse the source code

3) so, the best non-answer is to not waste too much time trying to sort out the reason why the compiler behaviour is inconsistent

4) if the optimisation is important to you, switch compiler